# How can I remove craft acrylic paint that has been mixed with silicone oil from multiple surfaces?

Tags: bathroom, repair, cleaning, paint-removal

I was making a layered cup of various acrylic paint mixed with floetral and silicone oil to do a acrylic pour/ flip cup painting. The cup slipped out of my hand and hit the edge of the bathtub, splashing onto the tile the bathrug, the toilet lid, the grout , The fixtures, the wall,and thoroughly saturating the bathtub, basically everything in the bathroom got some spatter on it. I rent my apartment so I need to clean it up ASAP and I can’t risk damage to any of the property for obvious reasons. I’m worried that using too harsh of a chemical will mess up the fiberglass bathtub or strip the paint off of the wall that was already there not just the paint that I splashed on there by accident. I tried to wipe up as much as possible but that seemed to make it worse and I didn’t want to permanently embed the paint into any porous surfaces by rubbing it in.

Comment: I'd start with soap and water.  That may remove most or all of it and should not cause any damage.

Comment: Paint thinner / mineral spirits

Answer (score 2):

If the spill has already dried it would be easiest to use a putty knife and scrap off as much as possible (for all surfaces). There will probably be some residual paint left, but by removing some through scraping it will be easier to clean with a fluid.

Once the scraping is done use a cleaning fluid such as lacquer thinner on the porcelain and tile surfaces. They won't be affected by the solvent. Use a bristle brush or terri-cloth to rub the spot away.

To clean the fiberglass surface try this product:[image]

Finally for the painted wall surface it may be simpler to touch-up paint the the spilled spots after lightly sanding them. If not you'll have to use a solvent such as the lacquer or Goo-Gone. This will dull the paint surface so unless it won't be noticeable you may end up painting anyway.